# Datatables: Ширина фиксированных столбцов в заголовке не совпадает с шириной в теле таблицы

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatable

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/DyMSb/1/

Скриншот: http://s17.postimg.org/dybznay9b/screen.png

Используются следующие версии:

- ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css
- ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css
- datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.js
- datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js
- datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/media/js/FixedColumns.js

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    var aoColumns = [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null];

    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sScrollXInner": "150%",
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "aoColumns": aoColumns       
    } );

    var oFC = new FixedColumns( oTable, {
        "iLeftColumns": 4
    } );

    oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
});
```

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" id="example">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th rowspan="2">Branch</th>
               <th rowspan="2">Object</th>
               <th rowspan="2">Address</th>
               <th rowspan="2">Count</th>
               <th colspan="7">Availability</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th>15</th>
               <th>16</th>
               <th>17</th>
               <th>18</th>
               <th>19</th>
               <th>20</th>
               <th>21</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>United States of America, Washington</td>
               <td>ABC-123</td>
               <td>1514 Amber Pond Highway, Nohead Bottom, Washington, 99205-8224, US, (425) 023-9448</td>
               <td><a href="#">7</a></td>
               <td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
               <td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>United States of America, South Dakota</td>
               <td>DEF-456</td>
               <td>7827 Stony Pointe, Sunsweet, South Dakota, 57006-2156, US, (605) 621-7800</td>
               <td><a href="#">7</a></td>
               <td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
               <td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>United States of America, Newfoundland</td>
               <td>XYZ-549</td>
               <td>2379 Dewy Pioneer Highlands, Humbug, Newfoundland, A7O-6P5, CA, (709) 217-5115</td>
               <td><a href="#">7</a></td>
               <td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
               <td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>United States of America, Washington</td>
               <td>GHI-789</td>
               <td>5842 Easy Bay, Kravaksarak, Washington, 98428-9376, US, (425) 998-1922</td>
               <td><a href="#">7</a></td>
               <td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
               <td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</body>
```

Дискуссия на родном форуме: http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/15133/fixed-column-header-width-does-not-match-body-column-widths#Item_1 и на StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054584/fixed-column-header-width-does-not-match-body-column-widths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поиграйте с параметрами колонок [`iLeftWidth`](http://datatables.net/docs/FixedColumns/2.0.3/91bce7c4ad.html#iLeftWidth) и [`sLeftWidth`](http://datatables.net/docs/FixedColumns/2.0.3/91bce7c4ad.html#sLeftWidth). Там плохо учитывается, что `td` может растянуться, если если какое-либо слово не влезает по ширине ячейки. Если задать ширину побольше, то все нормально.
При `iLeftWidth:120` и `sLeftWidth:'relative'`, например, все ок.